# Filtering YouTube Video URL

Tags: php, variables, youtube

I am making a YouTube tool, but I can't understand how to get the video ID in a PHP variable. Suppose a user type a youtube video url in my form which can be:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzOt12co4nk&feature=g-vrec
```

What is the way to filter the URL and get this video ID in a variable?

For example: `$vid` will have this video ID so it would be `$vid = YzOt12co4nk;` Please take a time to describe it, I'm a beginner in coding! Thanks

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzOt12co4nk&feature=g-vrec";
preg_match('/v=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', $url, $matches);
$vid = $matches[1];
```

Comment: can we filter google redirect urls to get that website  url in this same way? suppose: i want to get `$url=www.tv.com/news/celebrity-high-five-former-child-star-christine-lakin-al-from-step-by-step-on-her-5-favorite-tv-shows-29374/` from this url `http://www.google.com/url?sa=X&q=http://news.google.com/news/story%3Fncl%3Dhttp://www.tv.com/news/celebrity-high-five-former-child-star-christine-lakin-al-from-step-by-step-on-her-5-favorite-tv-shows-29374/%26hl%3Den%26geo%3Dus&ct=ga&cad=CAcQA` what is the exact way.. i have tried but failed :(

Comment: @itistg You should post a new question and include examples of what you have tried and a complete description of your problem.